# Node_modules installation fails on Debian 9

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've deployed my KeystoneJS project on GCP Compute Engine but when I run `npm_install` I catch an error. Maybe there is any way to fix it?

What I have done:

- created a VM instance that uses Debian 9.
- cloned repository with all the files to the new folder
- created an external IP address for my website

KeystoneJS uses `Node.js` and `MongoDB` and I have both installed.

```
nodejs --version
v12.14.1
```

```
npm --version
6.13.4
```

Then I've tried to install `node_modules` but the installation failed.

```
> kerberos@0.0.22 install /home/retvizanjr/seebelarus.by/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory '/home/retvizanjr/seebelarus.by/node_modules/kerberos/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
In file included from ../lib/kerberos.cc:1:0:
../lib/kerberos.h:5:27: fatal error: gssapi/gssapi.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gssapi/gssapi.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
kerberos.target.mk:113: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/retvizanjr/seebelarus.by/node_modules/kerberos/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.0-11-amd64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/retvizanjr/seebelarus.by/node_modules/kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v12.14.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
```

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/retvizanjr/seebelarus.by/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.0-11-amd64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/retvizanjr/seebelarus.by/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/retvizanjr/seebelarus.by/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.14.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/retvizanjr/.npm/_logs/2020-01-30T17_22_51_506Z-debug.log
```

I'm getting this error instead the first one after installing a Kerberos package

```
kerberos.target.mk:113: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/retvizanjr/seebelarus.by/node_modules/kerberos/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.0-11-amd64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/retvizanjr/seebelarus.by/node_modules/kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v12.14.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the Kerberos Development Package:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libkrb5-dev
```

Comment: Must I do it after ```npm install``` or before?

Comment: You should run these commands before trying to install `node_modules`.

Comment: I have installed it, but then when I ran ```npm install``` I got the same error.

Comment: Do you still have a `fatal error: gssapi/gssapi.h: No such file or directory` like on the 1st screeshot?

Comment: I've updated the question and added the code of the new error.

Comment: I found, that my template engine doesn't work and that's why I cannot see some elements on my website. Maybe this issue is connected with the errors I get?

Comment: Yes, it could  be connected, if you still have an error during installation.